# Datatables server-side processing com Sweet Alert 2

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, jquery-datatables

Estou utilizando o Datatables com server-side processing e utilizando o SweetAlert2 para confirmar antes de excluir o registro. Está tudo funcionando, menos o sweet alert que não é exibido ao clicar no link de excluir.

Usando o datatables sem ajax, o sweet alert funciona normal. Ao clicar no `<a class="dropdown-item sa-warning" style="cursor:pointer;" data-route="services/delete/' . $service->id . '">` onde tem a classe sa-warning, deveria chamar o script do sweet alert, mas nada acontece e não tem erro nenhum.

View

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Serviços')
@push('styles')
<link href="{{ asset('plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="{{ asset('plugins/datatables/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"/>
@endpush
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card-box table-responsive">
            <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                <a href="{{ route('services.create') }}" class="btn btn-custom waves-light waves-effect">Novo</a>
            </div>
            <table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th style="width: 5%">Ações</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
@push('scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/datatables/dataTables.buttons.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/datatables/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/datatables/jszip.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/datatables/pdfmake.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/datatables/vfs_fonts.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/datatables/buttons.html5.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('plugins/datatables/buttons.print.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">"use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#datatable').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                "method": "POST",
                "url": "{{ route('services.ajax.datatables') }}",
                "dataType": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                {"data": "name"},
                {"data": "actions", "searchable": false, "orderable": false}
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
@endpush
```

Sweet Alert

```
    $('.sa-warning').click(function () {
        $(this).each(function(){
            var route = $(this).data("route");
            swal({
                title: 'Você quer apagar o registro?',
                text: "Está ação não pode ser desfeita!",
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-confirm mt-2',
                cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-cancel ml-2 mt-2',
                cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
                confirmButtonText: 'Apagar!'
            }).then(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    url: route,
                    success:function(response){
                        window.location.href = response;
                    },
                    error:function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                })
            })
        });
    });
```

Routes

```
Route::post('services/ajax', 'ServiceController@ajaxDatatables')->name('services.ajax.datatables');
Route::get('services/delete/{service}', 'ServiceController@destroyServiceDatatables')->name('services.delete.datatables');
```

ServiceController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Service;
use App\Http\Requests\ServiceRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class ServiceController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    $services = Service::all();
    return view('service.index')
        ->with('services', $services);
}

public function ajaxDatatables(Request $request)
{
    $columns = [
        0 => 'name',
    ];

    $totalData = Service::count();
    $limit = $request->input('length');
    $start = $request->input('start');
    $order = $columns[$request->input('order.0.column')];
    $dir = $request->input('order.0.dir');

    if (empty($request->input('search.value'))) {
        $services = Service::offset($start)
            ->limit($limit)
            ->orderBy($order, $dir)
            ->get();
        $totalFiltered = Service::count();
    } else {
        $search = $request->input('search.value');
        $services = Service::where('name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
            ->offset($start)
            ->limit($limit)
            ->orderBy($order, $dir)
            ->get();
        $totalFiltered = Service::where('name', 'like', "%{$search}%")
            ->count();
    }

    $data = [];

    if ($services) {
        foreach ($services as $service) {
            $nestedData['name'] = $service->name;
            $nestedData['actions'] = '<div class="btn-group dropdown">
                                <a href="javascript: void(0);"
                                   class="table-action-btn dropdown-toggle arrow-none btn btn-light btn-sm"
                                   data-toggle="dropdown"
                                   aria-expanded="false">
                                    <i class="mdi mdi-dots-horizontal"></i>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="services/' . $service->id . '/edit">
                                        <i class="mdi mdi-pencil mr-2 text-muted font-18 vertical-middle"></i>Editar</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item sa-warning" style="cursor:pointer;"
                                       data-route="services/delete/' . $service->id . '">
                                        <i class="mdi mdi-delete mr-2 text-muted font-18 vertical-middle"></i>Excluir</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>';
            $data[] = $nestedData;
        }
    }

    $jsonData = [
        "draw" => intval($request->input('draw')),
        "recordsTotal" => intval($totalData),
        "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered),
        "data" => $data
    ];

    echo json_encode($jsonData);
}

public function create()
{
    return view('service.create');
}

public function store(ServiceRequest $request)
{
    $service = Service::create($request->all());
    Session::flash('alert-success', 'Serviço incluído com sucesso!');
    return redirect()->route('services.index');
}

public function edit(Service $service)
{
    return view('service.edit')
        ->with('service', $service);
}

public function update(ServiceRequest $request, Service $service)
{
    $service->update($request->all());
    Session::flash('alert-success', 'Serviço alterado com sucesso!');
    return redirect()->route('services.index');
}

public function destroy(Service $service)
{
    if ($service->orders->count() > 0) {
        Session::flash('alert-warning', 'Existem orçamentos com esse serviço!');
        return response(route('services.index'));
    } else {
        $service->delete();
        Session::flash('alert-success', 'Serviço excluído com sucesso!');
        return response(route('services.index'));
    }
}

public function destroyServiceDatatables(Service $service)
{
    $service->delete();
    Session::flash('alert-success', 'Serviço excluído com sucesso!');
    return redirect()->route('services.index');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema modificando a primeira linha do sweet alert de:

```
$('.sa-warning').click(function () {
```

para:

```
$("#datatable").on("click", ".sa-warning", function () {
```